# How can I find out the status of my UK visa application?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, application-status

I just got back my passport via DHL, after waiting one week. When I opened the package, it contained only my passport with absolutely nothing else in it, and not even a refusal letter. I applied at the TLS visa application center in Rome, and it doesn't have even a single phone number to contact them and ask about my situation.

I'm confused now and I have an emergency situation to go to London. When I tried to ask on its website, it states that I have to wait almost 20 days for a response.

I paid almost 260€ for priority visa processing (non-settlement). I tried to ask a British consultant and they said they can't help. I called the Embassy and, after I explained my situation, they said that they don't have any contact information for TLS. TLS listed some phone numbers but they are all wrong.

I don't know what to do. How can I find out what has happened?

Comment: First, is anything stamped in the passport? Second, is there anything in your life that would make your application more complicated than normal? TLS mention on their site that it could take longer in exceptional cases.

Comment: nothing is stamped in my passport . the application process is already finished and i have my passport back . the question is why i don't have refuse letter or Visa on my passport

Answer (score 3):

UK visa application centres do not allow phone contact, as consular staff are not allowed to engage the public directly. You can use the [TLS Rome](https://uk.tlscontact.com/it/rom/inquiry.php) web contact form to enquire although, as you note, it can take up to 20 days for a substantive response. However, you should get an initial reply within three business days.

You could also contact the [UK Visas and Immigration](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english) help centre, a fee-based service:

> You can call or email English-speaking* staff with a question about your application.
>
> By phone
>   Telephone: 00 44 203 481 1736
>   Monday to Friday, 24 hours
>   Calls cost £1.37 per minute on top of your standard network charges.
>
> By email
>   [Email UK Visas and Immigration](https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English). 
>   Emails enquiries cost £5.48. You will not be charged for any follow-up emails about the same enquiry.
>
> You’ll get a reply to your email within 2 days, except on Saturdays, Sundays and UK [public holidays](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays).

*Service is [available in other languages.](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk?previous_response=english)

Answer (score -2):

I think you should apply again and write them your situation and I don't think if there is any other way to communicate with them.